# Why can header.copy not be used in vcl_deliver?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I was wondering about an unexpected behaviour of varnish and the header vmod.
The following vcl will not compile, because of the use of `header.copy` in `vcl_deliver`.

Why is the use of `header.copy` not allowed here? Is there any documentation for this behaviour? Neither the documentation of varnish nor header say anything ybout it.

I don't need a workaround. I already have that.

```
vcl 4.1;

import header;
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8888";
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
  header.copy(beresp.http.Set-Cookie, beresp.http.X-Set-Cookie);
  unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  header.copy(beresp.http.X-Set-Cookie, beresp.http.Set-Cookie);
  unset beresp.http.X-Set-Cookie;
}
```

will result in the following error, when compiled

> Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev varnishd[12938]: Error: Feb 09 06:40:11
> epcentos7.dev varnishd[12938]: Message from VCC-compiler: Feb 09
> 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev varnishd[12938]: ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl'
> Line 15 Pos 15) -- (Pos 20) Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev
> varnishd[12938]: header.copy(beresp.http.X-Set-Cookie,
> beresp.http.Set-Cookie); Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev
> varnishd[12938]:
> --------------######--------------------------------------------
> Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev varnishd[12938]: Not available in subroutine
> 'vcl_deliver'. Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev varnishd[12938]: Running
> VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2 Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev
> varnishd[12938]: VCL compilation failed Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev
> systemd[1]: varnish.service: control process exited, code=exited
> status=255 Feb 09 06:40:11 epcentos7.dev systemd[1]: Failed to start
> Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `beresp` object is not available in `vcl_deliver` as it is part of a different flow. The equivalent would be `resp`, which would result in the following `header.copy()` line:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
  header.copy(resp.http.X-Set-Cookie, resp.http.Set-Cookie);
  unset resp.http.X-Set-Cookie;
}
```

### Transaction scope

Varnish has 2 kinds of transactions:

- *Client transactions*: requests being received from the client, and responses being served to the client
- *Backend transactions*: backend requests being sent to the backend, and backend responses being received from the backend

When a request results in a *cache hit*, Varnish only needs a *client transaction* to process it. No connection to the backend is made, so no *backend transaction* is used.

When a request results in a *cache miss*, Varnish will use both a *client transaction* to interact with the client, and a *backend transaction* to get the non-cached data from the backend

### Subroutine scope

With the *transaction scope* in mind, we can now map *VCL subroutines* to it.

Here's an overview of client-side subroutines:

- `vcl_recv`
- `vcl_hash`
- `vcl_miss`
- `vcl_hit`
- `vcl_pass`
- `vcl_deliver`
- `vcl_synth`
- `vcl_purge`

These transactions have access to the `req` object and the `resp` object for requests and responses.

There are also *backend subroutines* such as:

- `vcl_backend_fetch`
- `vcl_backend_response`
- `vcl_backend_error`

These subroutines have access to the `bereq` and `beresp` objects.

### Object flow

When a request is received, the request information is stored in the `req` object. When it the request results in a *cache miss*, the `req` object information is copied into the `bereq` object.

When the backend responds the `beresp` object contains the (potentially) cacheable information. The `beresp` object data is copied into the `obj` object which represents what is stored in cache, but also to the `resp` object that is used to serve the response to the client that requested it.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't see that.